# obtain conditional probability

Tags: conditional-probability

Two common coins are tossed.
a) Obtain the condiitional probability that both coins resulted in tails knowing that the first coin resulted in tail.
b) What is the conditional probability that we obtains tails on both coins knowing that at least of them is tail?